# PNG Images Not Showing on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, png

For some reason my png images on my side bar under the Amazon ad, along with the Patreon link on my header ad link, or Facebook link on the footer ad isn't showing. I am not sure if it's something wrong with my Firefox or possibly a coding error. On Chrome and Safari, they show without an issue. I have checked and my Firefox is up to date as well. http://www.4diyers.com/index.php

Comment: Do you have adblocker or another plugin?

Comment: you can't use `content` on generic elements in FF yet (non pseudo-element). So either style you `<a>` as block, with a background-image, either set the content on your elements' `::before` or `::after` pseudo-eleemnts (e.g `pinterest_s_link::before {
    content: url(../images/smpinterest.png);
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 77px;
}`)

Comment: Kaiido, awesome that worked perfectly! Thank you :)